# Backup Exec 2014 Setup

Tags: windows-server-2012, backupexec, windows-server-backup

So I'm really rusty when it comes to configuring Backup Exec 2014 to back up to tape library.

Current config
Server 2012
HP 1/8 G2 AutoLoader LTO4 via SAS Card

Can someone help me out. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvMDU.jpg)
Before powering on the Autoloader, it was logical that Tape storage option appears, but once I power on the unit, "Media Sets and Vaults" appear.

What is the best option to pick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tape drive and media set after. The tape drive is in backupexec the main unit that read the tape, while the media set is more for protecting each cartridge inside the loader. To prevent a accidental tape overwritting in example.